# Prevent closing form except on button

Tags: vb.net

I'm coding an application which is fullscreen.
I don't want anyone to be able to alt+tab/win+tab/alt+f4/alt+esc etc. out of the application.
I DO however have an 'administrator' PIN login, where doing so closes the form to show the desktop.

How do I go about stopping anyone closing the form, unless they enter the PIN?

Comment: You should avoid wasting your time trying to circumvent security features and instead look into using windows in kiosk mode.

Comment: It's a Windows 7 PC, which doesn't seem as simple as Win8, unfortunately!

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: WinForms - VB within Visual Studio 'Basic Form Application'.

Comment: There are a whole bunch more key combinations you need to check for Ctrl+Shift+Escape and Windows+R to name a couple which is why this is a futile exercise

Comment: **Update:** I've been able to obtain 8.1. Kiosk mode seems great, but I can only lock it down to a Metro app?

Answer (score -1):

The `Form.FormClosing` event is what you should handle. It supplies a `FormClosingEventArgs` argument with `CloseReason` and `Cancel` properties. This could be used to roughly handle your scenario.

This answer is not meant to turn your WinForms/Win7 app into a kiosk app. At best, you can prevent Alt+F4 or mouse attempts to close your applications. Do not waste your time trying to circumvent app switching. If Win 8 with kiosk mode is not a viable option for you, don't promise the same to your end users. In all other cases, your end users will have access to the whole OS at the level of the user currently signed in.

Comment: Thanks for this, when copying in I get all sorts of errors. I may be wrong but this looks more like Java than VB?

Comment: Why are you posting c# in a question tagged vb.net? Also `FormClosing` will not be able to intercept Alt+Tab type keypresses

Comment: C# apparently ^. I didn't think it was VB!

Comment: Should have mentioned that. This is C# code. If you have trouble porting it, let me know.

Comment: Much trouble... No idea about C# sorry!